# i don't understand A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: pandas, copy, slice, warnings

I have this code:

```
reg = XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree',
                       n_estimators=1000,
                       early_stopping_rounds=50,
                       objective='reg:linear',
                       max_depth=3,
                       learning_rate=0.01)


reg.fit(X_train, y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
        verbose=100)

test['prediction']=reg.predict(X_test)
```

i don't understand

:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
test['prediction']=reg.predict(X_test)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)